# Create and display Msgbox and output array contents and word lengths to worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a Msgbox that displays all of the words in a column on a worksheet. Then create another message box with the count of the number of words along with words with greater than 5 characters. I'm not quite sure of how to create the Msgbox with the below variables so I would appreciate some help!

So far I wrote a sub that imports a single line of text from a text file using GetOpenFilename. Then I used split to parse the file using a delimiter.

The contents of the text file are as follows:

Zags, Golden Eagles, Hawks, Peacocks, Greyhounds, Golden Griffens, Dons, Musketeers

Below is the code I have so far:

```
Sub ImportTextFile()

Dim fileName As Variant     ' array will hold the file name or names to import

Dim i As Integer            ' counter for loops
Dim nLargeWords As Integer  ' counter for words longer than 5 characters

Dim dataLine As String      ' string to hold a single line of text from file
Dim lineCount As Integer

Dim arrWords() As String    ' array that will hold the contents of the text file
Dim msg As String           ' string for building the first message box

Const delim = ","           ' Added a constant for the delimiter in Split function

With Range("Output_lbl")
         Range(.Offset(1, 1), .Offset(100, 2)).ClearContents
End With

'============Navigate to file location and get filename of text file


fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select a text file", , False)       ' Used GetOpenFilename method to navigate to the file and obtain the file name.


'============Import file into temp string variable then parse into an array


Open fileName For Input As #1       ' To open the text file.
    i = 0
    With Range("Output_lbl")
        Do Until EOF(1)

            Line Input #1, dataLine             ' Setting the first line of the text file to a string variable.
            arrWords() = Split(dataLine, delim)         ' Using Split to parse the file. The delimiter was determined to be "," which was declared a constant above.
            For i = LBound(arrWords()) To UBound(arrWords())        ' Parse into an array.
                .Offset(i, 0) = Trim(arrWords(i))
            Next i
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With

Close #1                            ' To close the text file.


'============Create and display the message boxes and output array contents and word lengths to the output sheet.


End Sub
```

One message box should be formatted like this:

Words in the file.

```
Zags
Golden Eagles
Hawks
Peacocks
Greyhounds
Golden Griffins
Dons
Musketeers
```

The other message box should be formatted like this:

Microsoft Excel

```
Total Words:    8
Large Words:    5
```

Answer (score 0):

Example code not using Array. You just need to modify the loop to look at a variable index in array rather variable row in column loop. Then, the logic used below should be easily extended to your problem.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Example()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Dim MyString As String, MyCounter As Long, Arr

LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LR
    MyString = MyString & ws.Range("A" & i) & ", "

    If Len(ws.Range("A" & i)) > 5 Then
        MyCounter = MyCounter + 1
    End If
Next i

MyString = Left(MyString, Len(MyString) - 2) 'Remove last ", "
Arr = Split(MyString, ", ")

MsgBox "Total Words: " & UBound(Arr) + 1 & vbNewLine & "Large Words: " & MyCounter


End Sub
```

[image]